# Looking for a simple way to find cumulative and aggregated counts of events across IDs where an ID may have one or more events

Tags: r, tidyverse, gtsummary

I am developing a report using Rmarkdown/Quarto for a study/trial. I want to generate a table of events that summarizes:

- Number of events that have occurred (overall and by specific event 'type')
- Proportion of persons who had an event (overall and by specific event 'type')

The data contain a row for each event and there may be more than one event per ID.

Here is a minimal dataset to explain:

```
set.seed(111)
dt <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1:10), each=2),
                 # serious = sample(c("Yes","No"), 20, replace = TRUE),
                 type = sample(c("A", "B", NA), 20, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.4, .4, .2)))
```

The desired table would have:

| Event type | Number of unique IDs with the event | Proportion of unique IDs with the event | Total number of events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Any event |  |  |  |
| Event "A" |  |  |  |
| Event "B" |  |  |  |
| Event "C" |  |  |  |

I have tried to use `dplyr` techniques to `group_by() |> summarize` (see below), and I can get close on some of the table cells but am struggling to get clean output and into the format that I'm hoping for.

```
dt |> 
  group_by(type) |> 
  summarize(unique_ids = n_distinct(id))
```

The above code does seem to give the correct counts of unique IDs for each type (A/B/NA) and accounts for an ID having more than one "A" for example. But it does not give the overall event row, and I can't figure out proportion of IDs, total events (ID can have more than one), etc.

For other tables within the report I have used the `tbl_summary` function from `gtsummary`, but for these data, the same ID can be in multiple rows and I do not think that package appropriately handles this type of data.

Comment: This package may have the functionality you're looking for. https://shannonpileggi.github.io/gtreg/

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. make small helper function:

```
f <- \(d) summarize(d, ids=n_distinct(id),prop_ids = ids/n_distinct(d$id), n = n())
```

2. Apply the function to the total frame, and a grouped version of the frame, and bind together:

```
bind_rows(
  f(dt) %>% mutate(type="Any"),
  f(group_by(dt,type))
)
```

Output:

```
  ids prop_ids  n type
1  10      1.0 20  Any
2   8      0.8 10    A
3   8      0.8  9    B
4   1      0.1  1 <NA>
```